# Cardinality of two infinite subsets of the naturals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How is it possible to show that the cardinality of sets $\mathbb S$ and $\mathbb T$ is the same?

$\mathbb S =\{1\} \bigcup\{2^{(n-1)} + n : n \in \mathbb N \land n>1\}$

$\mathbb T = \{m : m \in \mathbb N \land m \notin \mathbb S \}$

The simple answer is that they are both subsets of $\mathbb N$ so the cardinality will be $\aleph_0$ for both sets.

The thing that puzzles me is that if set $\mathbb S$ has n members then set $\mathbb T$ will have $2^{n}$ members, which is the same as the number of members in the power set of $\mathbb S$. And we hold that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb S)$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$

Comment: This just goes to show that some intuition doesn't translate well to infinity. The two sets' cardinalities are indeed equal.

Comment: The cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{S})$ is *not* $\aleph_1$ unless the continuum hypothesis holds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your simple answer is correct.  Once you establish they are both infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$, they both have cardinality $\aleph_0$.  $\Bbb T$ will not have as many elements as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb S)$.  It is true that you can define $S(m) =\{1\} \bigcup_n\{2^{(n-1)} + n : n \in \mathbb N \land m \ge n>1\}$, which will have $m$ members and $T(m)=\{n: n\lt 2^{m-1}+m \wedge n \not \in S(m)\}$ and $T(m)$ will have $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb S(m))=2^m$ members.  But when you say $\Bbb T=\bigcup_n T(n)$ it is a countable union of finite sets, which is countable.